# PHP file_get_contents with if/else

Tags: php

On this [link I was learning about file_get_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384152/php-file-get-contents) and I'd like to incorporate it into a simple if/else statement but can't seem to get it correct.

I'd like to check if the file exists and if not, display a no_image.jpg graphic.

My struggle is that the  tag already has a PHP echo so it is causing the snippet to stop working.  How do I format the if/else while still haveing the  use the dynamic value from the echo if file_get_contents is true?

Currently I have a simple  tag like this:

```
<img width="200" height="150" src="images/<?php echo(rawurlencode($row['MLS_NUMBER'])); ?>_1.jpg" alt="" align="left" vspace="3" hspace="3" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically:

```
<?php

if (file_exists(...)) {
  $path = ...;
} else {
  $path = 'no_image.jpg';
}
?>

<img src="images/<?php echo $path; ?>" />
```

//add a semicolon after echo $path otherwise it won't work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for a jpg file based on $row['MLS_NUMBER']

```
<img width="200" height="150" src="images/
<?php 
 if (file_exists($row['MLS_NUMBER']) {
       echo(rawurlencode($row['MLS_NUMBER'])).'_1.jpg';
     } else {
       echo "no_image.jpg";
     }
 ?>" alt="" align="left" vspace="3" hspace="3" />
```

Comment: How does php know what directory and file extension to looks for with file exists?  Don't you need to specify path and .jpg...otherwise it is just looking for the number?

I tried this with no luck?

Comment: I tried this with no luck?

if (file_exists(."/images/".$row['MLS_NUMBER']."_1.jpg"))

Comment: @Rocco. The code given is an example. I don't know which jpg you want to show. PHP will NOT know where your graphics are, so you need to add a directory to $row['MLS_NUMBER']. So if for example you have an a graphic named /images/234666234_1.jpg where 234666234 is the MLS number coming in via $row array, then you would write `if(file_exists("/images/{$row['MLS_NUMBER']}_1.jpg")`  etc. Your code may have failed because of the additional . (dot) in the `file_exists(."/images` line.